# Interactive Web Component

Tags: ilnumerics

Is there a way to use the Interactive Web Component in a self hosted solution? At my work, we could perhaps use something like this, as demonstrated here:
http://ilnumerics.net/ilnumerics-interactive-web-component.html

I saw that the ILView over at github has a viewer and a C# REPL, but I'm not sure if this works in the browser. We really would love to see something like the Interactive Web Components on the corporate intranet.

Comment: Ever heard of Cammy for AngularJS ? http://lorem--ipsum.github.io/cammy/

Comment: @LoremIpsum, what I would like is something where a viewer and a REPL that can execute .NET, is accessible via the browser.

Comment: @Mark Wrobel It is not for the public (yet). Please write us an pm: info@ilnumerics.net. Maybe we can work something out...

Comment: @HaymoKutschbach thank you for the reply. We will consider contacting, when we are further in our considerations. The Interactive Web Component looks great. Keep up the good work! It's very inspiring :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Internet Web Components from ILNumerics are not public yet. See the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954408/interactive-web-component#comment27995885_18954408).

An alternative could be an [IPython Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/) server that uses IronPython as an interpreter as described [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#wiki-q-can-ipython-run-under-ironpython). But that seems to require giving up on a C# REPL and using a Python REPL instead.